# How to do a loop for a timer in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am trying to code a timer in UWP.
I want my timer to do a loop which counts down for example 1 minutes, then counts down a 2 minute pause, all that 5 times in a row, without having to re-press the start button.
I am able to count down the 1 minutes and get into the 2 minute pause but I can't figure out how to get back into the 1 minutes count down. The loop is just stuck in the 2 minute pause.

I have tried to do a IF, ELSE. I have tried bool, true, false..

```
 public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {

         public int x;


        static FenetreParametres infopage = FenetreParametres.Current;
        static int Task = Int32.Parse(infopage.getTmpRound());
        //static int nb = Int32.Parse(infopage.getNbRound());
        //static int pause = Int32.Parse(infopage.getTmpPause());
        MediaPlayer player;

    private int _restsTaken { get; set; }
        private int _currentTime { get; set; }
        private DispatcherTimer _timer { get; set; }
        private TimeSpan _tickInterval { get; set; }
        private TimeSpan _intervalRemainingTime { get; set; }
        private DateTime _intervalEnd { get; set; }
        private bool _isRunning = false;

        private bool verif = false;

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();            
            _currentTime = 0;
            _tickInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
            this.initializeTimer(_tickInterval.Seconds);


            this.initializeDisplayTimer(0);
            player = new MediaPlayer();

        }

        private void initializeTimer(int tickInterval)
        {
            _timer = new DispatcherTimer();
            _timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(tickInterval);
            _timer.Tick += interval_Tick;
        }

        private void initializeDisplayTimer(int intervalTime)
        {
            _intervalRemainingTime = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(intervalTime);
            timerLabel.Text = _intervalRemainingTime.ToString();
        }

        private void interval_Tick(object sender, object e)
        {

            int previousTimeInMinutes = _intervalRemainingTime.Minutes;
            _isRunning = true;
            _intervalRemainingTime = _intervalRemainingTime.Subtract(_tickInterval);
            timerLabel.Text = _intervalRemainingTime.ToString();

            if (previousTimeInMinutes != _intervalRemainingTime.Minutes)
            {
                string timeIndicator = _intervalRemainingTime.Minutes == 0 ? "1 >" : _intervalRemainingTime.Minutes.ToString();

            }
            if (TimeSpan.Equals(_intervalRemainingTime, TimeSpan.Zero))
            {
                playmusic();
                this.initializeDisplayTimer(2);



            }

        }

        private async void playmusic()
        {
            Windows.Storage.StorageFolder folder = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFolderAsync(@"Assets");
            Windows.Storage.StorageFile file = await folder.GetFileAsync("ding.wav");

            player.AutoPlay = false;
            player.Source = MediaSource.CreateFromStorageFile(file);

            player.Play();
        }

        private void trait()
        {

            for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
            {
                //timerLabel.Text = "Pause";
                //x = duree;
                playmusic();
                _currentTime = x;
                this.initializeDisplayTimer(_currentTime);
                x--;
                _intervalEnd = DateTime.Now.Add(_intervalRemainingTime);

                _timer.Start();


            }

        }

        private void Button_Click_Start(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            if (TimeSpan.Equals(_intervalRemainingTime, TimeSpan.Zero))
            {
                playmusic();
                this.initializeDisplayTimer(Task);
                _timer.Start();
            }

        }

        private void Button_Click_Pause(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _isRunning = false;
            _timer.Stop();

        }

        private void Button_Click_Reset(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _timer.Stop();

            this.initializeDisplayTimer(_currentTime);
        }
}
```

It's expected to go into the pause for 2 minutes and then get back into the 1 minute countdown, 5 times in a row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question actually is a basic c# code logic issue. It's not specific to UWP programming. If you understand the whole logic clearly, it's easy to get your target by c# code logic.

I just made a simple code sample for your reference:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="Count Down Time: "></TextBlock>
    <TextBlock x:Name="countDown1" Grid.Column="1"></TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="Pause Remaning: "></TextBlock>
    <TextBlock x:Name="pauseRemaning" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"></TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Text="Looping Times: "></TextBlock>
    <TextBlock x:Name="loop_Times" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"></TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    private int countDowm = 60;
    private int RemainingTime = 120;
    private int loopTimes = 0;

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
        timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
        timer.Start();
    }

    private void Timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
    {
        if (loopTimes == 5)
        {
            countDowm = 60;
            RemainingTime = 120;
            loopTimes = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            if (countDowm <= 0)
            {
                if (RemainingTime <= 0)
                {
                    loopTimes++;
                    countDowm = 60;
                    RemainingTime = 120;
                }
                else
                {
                    RemainingTime--;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                countDowm--;
            }
        }

        countDown1.Text = countDowm.ToString();
        pauseRemaning.Text = RemainingTime.ToString();
        loop_Times.Text = loopTimes.ToString();
    }
}
```